# Grails import NetBeans error

Tags: grails, netbeans

I have this code in the top of my `main.gsp` file

```
<%@ page import="com.somethingToImport"%>
```

NetBeans is giving me an error: `expecting EOF, found 'import' @ line 1, column 20`
I think this is causing my app to crash in IE. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what's the IE error?  Also - i think this is just a bug in the IDE code parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help the IE issue but won't fix NetBeans complaining. Try including the `DOCTYPE` in the first line of the GSP.

Example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <%@ page import="com.somethingToImport" %> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

*Note: I added a space between the import and the '%'*